# How to get WebStorm code formatting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

In the company we are using WebStorm for React, and for the last 3 years I have been working in VS Code.

Is there a way to get exact code formatting for all languages in VS Code as in WebStorm on default settings, and how to achieve that in order to prevent unnecessary diffs in git?

I can only tweak VS Code settings, I must not touch WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same formatting/functionality as Webstorm, I suggest using VS Code **extensions**. You will find an extension for almost every language/framework available on the [VS Code marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).

Here is a **[list of recommended extensions](https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/moving-from-webstorm-phpstorm-to-vs-code/)** that makes **VS code behave as Webstorm**.

For your particular case, I suggest you to use and configure [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

**Note** that you might not want to install too many extensions but only the ones you need because loading too many extensions will probably slow down your IDE.